# Missing expression after unary operator '--'

Tags: .net, powershell, .net-core

This is my first post so apologies for any mistakes.

I ran the *dotnet* command in the Windows Powershell and It gave me a description of how to use it:

```
Usage: dotnet [host-options] [command] [arguments] [common-options]

Common options:  
  -v|--verbose          Enable verbose output  
  -h|--help             Show help
```

When I ran the command

```
dotnet run -h|--help
```

It gave me the following error:

```
At line:1 char:17
+ dotnet run -h|--help
+                 ~
Missing expression after unary operator '--'.
At line:1 char:15
+ dotnet run -h|--help
+               ~~
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
At line:1 char:17
+ dotnet run -h|--help
+                 ~~~~
Unexpected token 'help' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Why is the command not showing help as intended? Having searched everywhere, I haven't been able to get a conclusive answer.

Comment: Use `dotnet -h` or `dotnet --help`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`-v|--verbose` means you can use either `-v` or `--verbose` ; the `|` in this context is [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)'s 'or' symbol.

Many options come in short form with a single (or few) letters mnemonic, or in long form which is more descriptive of the option. The short form will start with a single dash, while the long form starts with two dashes.

`|` in the context of `powershell` is a pipe, which separates commands, and the errors you see is the interpreter trying to make sense of `--help` as a command : it understands `--` as the unary minus, but can't make sense of `help` in that context.

You probably want to use `dotnet run -h`.

Comment: Haha That makes sense now. Thanks for the explanation!!